# Find word in line and count number of line

Tags: python

In file:

```
aaa 012 345
abc deg hij
hij aaa 075
aaa 345 658
```

I tried:

```
filer = file.read().split('\n')
count = 0
for line in filer:
    lines = line.split(' ')
    for words in lines:
        #print words, lines.count(words)
        if words in set(lines):
            count = count + 1
            print words, ', count line: ', count
```

The results showed:

```
aaa , count line:  1
012 , count line:  2
345 , count line:  3
abc , count line:  4
deg , count line:  5
hij , count line:  6
hij , count line:  7
aaa , count line:  8
075 , count line:  9
aaa , count line:  10
345 , count line:  11
658 , count line:  12
```

I want to count and print total number of line that contain each word in line. 
(Sorry about my explanation.)

Expected results:

```
aaa , count line: 3
012 , count line: 1
345 , count line: 2

abc , count line: 1
deg , count line: 1
hij , count line: 2

hij , count line: 2
aaa , count line: 3
075 , count line: 1

aaa , count line: 3
345 , count line: 2
658 , count line: 1
```

Any suggestion to print the expect result in order with the original line?

As I need them to be in order for using to calculate "the term frequency of the word that used in line frequency".

For example: the frequency of 'aaa' will be calculated by using the total number of lines divide by the numbers of lines that contain word 'aaa'.

Comment: A suggestion? You should try to formulate an specific question. What is not working? Where are you having problems?

Comment: how about using a dict?

Comment: Why is the total count for words inlucded multiple times in the expected output?

Comment: `words in set(lines)` does not do what you want.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. *"the frequency of 'aaa' will be calculated by using the total number of lines divide by the numbers of lines that contain word 'aaa'."* . that's clear. But the other sentence I don't understand, particularly *"that used in line frequency"*.

Comment: Also, you said something about "tf–idf" - so, the lines are your documents, and the whole file is your corpus? Can you give a formula for the value you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is made for exacly this purpose:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

with open('data.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        counter.update(line.split())

for item, count in counter.items():
    print "%s , count: %s" % (item, count)
```

Output:

```
abc, count: 1
aaa, count: 3
345, count: 2
012, count: 1
075, count: 1
hij, count: 2
658, count: 1
deg, count: 1
```

---

**Edit**: I'm still a bit unclear about what end result you're looking for, but this produces the exact output you asked for:

```
from collections import Counter

line_frequencies = Counter()

with open('data.txt') as data:
    lines = [line.split() for line in data]

for line in lines:
    unique_line = set(line)
    line_frequencies.update(unique_line)


for line in lines:
    for term in line:
        print "%s , count line: %s" % (term, line_frequencies[term])
    print "\n"
```

Comment: It cannot print out with original line in order, right? For example; aaa 012 345:: aaa , count line: 3; 012 , count line: 1; 345 , count line: 2

Comment: You could also teach the OP about the `Counter.most_common()` method to order words by frequency (most frequent first).

Comment: @ThanaDaray It can do whatever you want. But since you didn't answer my question as to why you want the totals in the output multiple times, I don't really understand what output exactly you want and why.

Comment: @ThanaDaray ok, please update your question accordingly (by giving the definition of the output in addition to the example).

Comment: @LukasGraf Thank you for your answer. I tried to understand them. From lines = [line.split() for line in data] , could you explain why you use them instead of make list after for loop. Sorry for asking lots.

Comment: @ThanaDaray that is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It basically is syntactic sugar that allows you to write simple `for` loops as an expression.

Comment: @LukasGraf Ah! I normally use after loop. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You need to tie your count to each individual variable. I suggest you try something like

```
file = open("this.txt",r)
tokenCount = {}

for line in file:
  for token in line.split(' '):
    if token in tokenCount.keys():
      tokenCount[token] += 1
    else:
      tokenCount[token] = 1 

for item in tokenCount:
  print item, ' , count line: ' tokenCount[item]
```

Your output is a bit unnecessary. It seems to know how many times a token appears before it reads that far cannot see any need to to it that way.